# how to get thumb url by product id in virtuemart

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

i want to get the Product's thumb url, i have assigned the product id to $pro_id.

> ```
> JHTML::_('link', JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id='.$pro_id.'&virtuemart_category_id='.$product->virtuemart_category_id),$product->images[0]->displayMediaThumb('class="catImage" border="0"',false));
> ```

it gives me  error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the situation for a virtuemart 2.x search component which i am developing and used following which worked.

```
<?php
 $pid= $item->virtuemart_product_id; // product id here
$sql="select i.file_url_thumb as image from #__virtuemart_medias as i, 
#__virtuemart_product_medias as mi where 
i.virtuemart_media_id = mi.virtuemart_media_id and 
mi.virtuemart_product_id =".$pid."  limit 0,1";

// Get a db connection.
$dbb = JFactory::getDbo();
$dbb->setQuery($sql);
$results = $dbb->loadObjectList();
?>

<img src="<?php  echo JURI::root () . $results[0]->image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->order_item_name;?>" />
```